# Get all postcodes on a given location using any Google API

Tags: google-api

Is it possible to get all postal codes in a given location inside the given radius?

What Google API should I use?

Example: I have a lat. and a long. and my radius is 15kms. How do I get the post codes of the areas inside the radius?

I'm kinda new to using API's and Google API's.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a process called "Reverse Geocoding" Google offers it here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

However pretty sure that Google's API will try to give you one closest result rather than many.

You can do this with APIs (often paid for) however, be warned that you have to be quite careful with the radius element, setting it too small in rural areas will bring back 0 results and setting it too big in urban areas will bring back potentially thousands.